# How to use a array of strings as a options in the react-select

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-select

I am new to `react`. I am using `react select` for the select.
Now, I have the following `jsx`

```
div className="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center" style={borderClass}>
                <label className="mb-0 font-weight-bold" style={labelFont}>
                  Technology
                                </label>
                <Select
                  styles={styles}
                  options={this.props.technology}
                  placeholder="None Selected"
                />
              </div>


const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    technology : state.CreateJob.technology,
    userCompany: state.CreateJob.userCompany
  }
}
```

this is coming from the reducer as a prop. Now, the data I am getting is like ,

```
['a', 'b', 'c']
```

So, How can I use this as a option in the render . Can any one help me with this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You can render a list like this :

```
var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var technologyList = [];
array1.forEach(function(element) {
    technologyList.push({ label:element, value: element })
});
```

And use it:

```
<Select options={ technologyList } />
```

Comment: What if I have a single string value like "abcd" and I want it be autoselect with this value

Comment: You will find what you need in this link : https://appdividend.com/2018/10/19/react-dropdown-select-example-tutorial/

Answer (score 3):

```
<Select 
options={options} 
getOptionLabel={option => option} 
getOptionValue={option => option}
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be supported https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/5032#issuecomment-1027629069

Comment: It doesn't support using array of strings like this. You have to make it object which returns label and value.

Answer (score 1):

React select expect options props as array of object with property value and label

```
 <Select
   styles={styles}
   options={this.props.technology.map(t=>({value: t, label: t}))}
   placeholder="None Selected"
 />
```

Comment: I have used this sol. but it haS 2200 items. so this thing is getting hanged

Comment: If I have a single string and I want it be autoselect then what is the way to do ut

Comment: Hi @aseferov could you please look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057517/how-to-reuse-the-container-logic-in-two-diff-places

Answer (score 1):

React-Select expects an array of objects for options with this format:

```
[..., { value: 'optionValue', label: 'optionLabel' }, ...]
```

The label property is displayed to the user and value will be sent to server on form submit.

You so you need to create an array in the given format from the array received from redux store.

```
...
render(){
    const { technology } = this.props;
    const rsOptions = technology.map(x => {label: x, value: x});
    return (
        <div className="col-md-4 d-flex align-items-center" style={borderClass}>
            <label className="mb-0 font-weight-bold" style={labelFont}>Technology</label>
                <Select
                    styles={styles}
                    options={rsOptions}
                    defaultValue={{label: 'abcd', value: 'abcd'}}
                    // value={{label: 'abcd', value: 'abcd'}}  // use value instead of defaultValue if its an controlled input
                    // you can also use an object from your array by index
                    // defaultValue={rsOptions[0]}
                    // or you can use find in your array
                    // defaultValue={rsOptions.find(x => x.value === 'abcd)}
                    placeholder="None Selected"
                />
          </div>
    );
}
...
```

Comment: could you please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55057517/how-to-reuse-the-container-logic-in-two-diff-places

Answer (score 0):

You must re-map your array of string to an array of object, react-select accept this format for options prop.

`[{ value: 'your value', label: 'your label' }]`

`<Select options={this.props.technology.map(t => ({ value: t, label: t})) } />`

Checkout the official docs [here](https://react-select.com/home)!

Answer (score -1):

you need to use map to traverse the array and render a option for
render each piece of the array.

```
<select className="form-control" value={currentValue} onChange={onChange}>
            <option value="">
                Select one...
            </option>
            {array.map(text,i => (
                <option key={i} value={text}>
                    {text}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
```